# How to get sh script’s own path, even through `.`

Tags: shell, posix, sh

I found different solutions to get an sh script's own path, but none of them work in pure POSIX sh through a `.`.
The solutions I have until now :

```
dirname $(readlink -f $0)
```

works in sh, but gives the parent script's path as `$0` is process-dependent (See above)

```
${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
```

which is obviously a bash-only solution.

The proof this solutions do not work :

```
$ tree --noreport
.
├── script1.sh
└── src
    └── script2.sh

$ cat script1.sh 
#!/bin/sh
. src/script2.sh

$ cat src/script2.sh 
#!/bin/sh
echo '$0 :' $(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
echo '$BASH_SOURCE :' $BASH_SOURCE

$ sh script1.sh 
$0 : /tmp/sof
$BASH_SOURCE :
```

What can I write in script2.sh to get the correct /tmp/sof/src directory ?

Comment: Not sure that it will work anyway, Script2.sh is sourced, not executed and used like it is **in** script1.sh during execution more or less. It fells crazy that bash has a way to *work around* this....

Comment: possible duplicate or reason to migrate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4650

Comment: @Harald This answer given does not work in this case. The solution given for tcsh detects if the script is sourced, but does not give the path.

Comment: @Olli Thank you for your comment. It means it is more a paradigm problem. Transforming to a classic sh script call is the solution, I guess. I just need a way to pass the variables to the parent script.

Comment: Try to work around the need of the scripts path in script2.sh somehow? Or set it in script1.sh where you a) know get the directory where script1.sh is in and b) know the relative path of where script2.sh lives?

Comment: @Olli The idea behind this question was to add a directory to the PATH inside script2.sh. I follow your suggestion a). An installation step writes a line in script2.sh to make it aware of his location. Like virtualenv does... Thank you for your help. You can write an answer to that, and I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is more or less impossible to find out the directory where script2.sh is in when you source it in script1.sh, try to work arround it. You can also find the directory of script1 inside script1.sh and you know the relative path of script2.sh as well in script1. You can then set an environment variable in script1.sh pointing to the directory of script2.sh before you source it. Then you can access this variable in script2.sh

Comment: Not the best idea as I want `script2.sh` to be as easy as possible to use from `script1.sh`. Exporting an environment variable before sourcing a script is not that easy. But through an installation step, I hard-write the location of `script2.sh` inside the script it self. I accept your answer, as my workaround does not answer my first question, but your answer does.